# Laptop freezes with ubuntu 19.10

Tags: kernel, laptop, asus, freeze

Using ubuntu 19.10 and my laptop randomly freezes and I have to restart it.
Tried many new kernel versions 5+ and they are all the same.
I found one kernel that doesnt freezes 4.20-generic.
What showld be the reason that I cant use newer one kernels?
What do I lose using older one kernel? 
Asus x555uj, 
GeForce 920m,
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz

Comment: You will need to edit your question with computer make and model, plus the cpu and graphics as well.  We would only be able to guess right now till we have more information.  Others might asked for different info.

Comment: Ok I have edited it.

Comment: Googled around a bit and have not found much useful so far.  New kernels usually have updated drivers for newer hardware, but if 4.20 is working good for you, keep it for now.  Just be careful that updates don't removed it.